# Change variable / int when string is empty

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I am trying to calculate the height of a label so I can set the height of its cell dynamically. This works fine, like this:

```
let commentText = itemsFeed[indexPath.item].comment
let commentRect = NSString(string: commentText!).boundingRect(with:CGSize(width: rectWidth, height: 1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
let commentHeight = ceil(commentRect.height)
```

This returns all the right values and I can dynamically set the height based on commentHeight.

However, when I don't add a comment, I would like to return 0 for commentHeight, but instead Swift returns 20 (the default height of a one line label). How can I override this?

I have tried to add an if statement like this:

```
if(commentText?.isEmpty)! {

    let commentHeight = 0

} else {

    let commentText = itemsFeed[indexPath.item].comment
    let commentRect = NSString(string: commentText!).boundingRect(with:CGSize(width: rectWidth, height: 1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
    let commentHeight = ceil(commentRect.height)

}
```

But this returns *Use of unresolved identifier 'commentHeight'* in the return of my CGSize (where commentHeight is called for).

Any tips or tricks on how to achieve this, so that commentHeight would be 0 if there is no text?

(All code presented is inside the sizeForItemAt method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable exists inside braces where it was declared only. Try this:

```
let commentHeight: CGFloat
if(commentText?.isEmpty)! {
    commentHeight = 0
} else {
    let commentText = itemsFeed[indexPath.item].comment
    let commentRect = NSString(string: commentText!).boundingRect(with:CGSize(width: rectWidth, height: 1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
    commentHeight = ceil(commentRect.height)
}
```

Comment: Do you now how to use optional chaining? `if(commentText?.isEmpty)! {` ??? Why don't you simply force unwrap the optional at its origin? `if commentText!.isEmpty {` note that this might crash your app the correct syntax is `if commentText?.isEmpty == true {`

Comment: Yes, you are right. This code is far from ideal. But my idea was to answer the question with minimal changes of the initial code to help topic starter to understand why his(her) sample doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to right that is:

```
let commentHeight: CGFloat = commentText?.isEmpty == true ? 0 : ceil(NSString(string: itemsFeed[indexPath.item].comment!).boundingRect(with:CGSize(width: rectWidth, height: 1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil).height)
```

(I would prefer it if the force unwrapping was avoided, and use `if-let` or `guard` or `??` when dealing with optionals)

Comment: Would it be beneficial to use this method instead of the if-statement? I mean - it might look better, but does it have a negative impact on the performance of my app, or potential crashes etc?

Comment: It is less verbose. Use the ternary operator `...? ... : ...` when you know you want to give a value to a variable depending on a condition

Comment: `(commentText?.isEmpty)!` ??? the correct and safe syntax is syntax `commentText?.isEmpty == true`

Answer (score -1):

If u need to resize a label based on its content u can set 0 in number of lines, using interface builder. Then the label will automatically resize for u.

Comment: Not trying to resize the label - that's perfectly fine already with, indeed, numberOfLines. However, I am now resizing the cell the label is in, based on the height of this label.